# How can i resize the array while summing two element?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

Imagine i have an array like this `{7, 2, 8, 9, 4, 13, 7, 1, 9, 10}`
and i want to have this array  `{9, 17, 17, 8, 19}`.

The first pair from the original list is Collapsed into 9 (7 + 2), the second pair is Collapsed into 17 (8 + 9), and so on.

My problem is how can i resize the initial array in C#?

I don't want to use another array with half size of initial array and I can't use List.

Comment: Use a generic `List` and don't worry about re-sizing hard-coded array sizes?

Comment: Note that the OP mentioned they cannot use List. @mobikaoxox Is there any reason to as why not? Is this part of an assignment where you only work with arrays?

Comment: Which part of the problem are you stuck on: 1) summing pairs, 2) collapsing the collection? Have you looked up the docs for available Array methods? What have you tried?

Comment: When you have a restriction that prevents you from using a perfectly adequate solution (in this case, `List`), you need to provide an explanation for why that is.

Comment: The only and the real solution is custom class, with array this[int] accessor implementation and interfaces IList<T>, ICollection<T>, probably with WeakReference and IDisposable item containers implementation

Answer (score 1):

The only method that can resize an array is [Array.Resize()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_Resize__1___0____System_Int32_). However, as stated in the remarks :

> This method allocates a new array with the specified size, copies elements from the old array to the new one, and then replaces the old array with the new one.

Meaning what you are asking is actually not possible.

Now we can question the why. Why don't you want another array ?

You could replace the old array by this one, the Garbage Collector will take care of cleaning the old array. But that would be the same as using the Resize() method.

You could use a List<>, but apparently you can't. May you elaborate on why is that ? List<> is available in all .Net frameworks and libraries.

Based on what you are asking, this looks a lot like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/319999)

Comment: Yes, abstract Array class do not contains methods to shrink itself, by design, for a big reasons related to GC and memory management. Except Span<T>, Memory<T> structures, which are also cant shrink array.

Answer (score 0):

You cant resize initial array, in C#. [Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/) in C# are not resizable. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.7.2

```cs
int[] array = { 7, 2, 8, 9, 4, 13, 7, 1, 9, 10 };
```

You can't resize this array.

Answer (score 0):

Pleas review [this code example](https://www.dotnetperls.com/array-resize).

It seems you need to use `Array.Resize` method (MSDN link is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.resize?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

Code snippet:

```
var arr = int[10] {7, 2, 8, 9, 4, 13, 7, 1, 9, 10};
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
   arr[i]=arr[i] + arr[i+1];
}
Array.Resize(ref arr, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple implementation using array only. First we traverse the array and every second element we perform a sum. The second element is then removed and in his place we put a flag (-1000).

I then use the simple logic for the bubble sort algorithm , but we only swap when we find our flag. Therefor all our sum are on the left of the array, meanwhile the flags are on the right.

I then use the Take method to take the half of the results.

```
        int flag = -1000;
        int[] myValues = new int[] { 7, 2, 8, 9, 4, 13, 7, 1, 9, 10 };
        for (int i = 0; i < myValues.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 != 0 && i != 0)
            {
                myValues[i - 1] = myValues[i] + myValues[i - 1];
                myValues[i] = flag;
            }
        }
        //clean up remove unwanted flags
        for (int i = 0; i < myValues.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < myValues.Length; j++)
            {
                if (myValues[i] == flag)
                {
                    var temp = myValues[j];
                    myValues[j] = myValues[i];
                    myValues[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        myValues = myValues.Take(myValues.Length / 2).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

Put sum of ith & i+1th element at location i, delete element at i+1, repeat.

```
  private static List<int> solution(List<int> arr) {
    int s = arr.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i += 1) {
      arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i + 1];
      arr.RemoveAt(i + 1);
      s -= 1;
    }
    return arr;
  }
```

Comment: this is not resizes initial array

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this is so?

Comment: by design, abstract class Array do not have method to shrink its size, and you are not using `C# arrays` at all in you answer, so it is not related to question `how can be initial array be shrinked half in size`. Answer is - no way you can do this, until you are using C# arrays, not `Span<T>`, `Memory<T>` or other structures, which is not C# array anyway.

Comment: I am using the List generic class, not the abstract class Array. Do you mean to say the List generic class cannot be resized? If so, I believe you are incorrect.
I did not see the question's statement that they "can't use List", though, so you are correct that this answer is irrelevant.